# How to get static Ip or Public Ip from Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, azure-storage, static-ip-address

I have developed a windows server application and this application will be connecting to the different client mobile application. Currently, I got the Static IP from my service provider and I'm using in my home. But I can't able to maintain the server for 24/7. So, I'm planning to publish the Server application in Microsoft Azure or any cloud.

But I cant able to find any information about the static IP information in Microsoft Azure. Or Can I use Amazon web services. And the server application also uses the Microsoft SQL Server 2008. So Please guide me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you publishing an Azure Website, or a Virtual Server?  Either way, after you publish your selected technology, the specific information about that service, including it's public address, will be visible in your azure dashboard.

Comment: as to costs for services, this isn't really something we can answer.

Comment: I have developed the normal windows server application using Delphi programming. And from mobile I'm connecting to the server application using IP address and port. So, I'm having doubt that whether Microsoft Azure will provide the Static IP or not?

Comment: why would they not? how else would you be able to access the resource you have published there?

Comment: No. Currently I have published in my personal system where I have got the static IP and I have not published in cloud. I cant able to find the exact details in internet. Please provide me the more information for the accessing Static ip machine in cloud

Comment: the exact details are: Step 1 publish the app.  Step 2 read the IP assigned to the app printed in the azure dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short : don't do it !

You should never rely on an IP address but on a domain name instead. Every cloud provider will give you a subdomain (such as blabla.cloudapp.net for Azure VM) that will hide the complexity of load balancing + fail overing.